# dynamically updating table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, magento

I am using magento and am trying to customize the shopping cart. Basically i have a table and i am trying to change the inner html for the table rows. I am currently selected all the classname by "item-options" and then changing hte inner html. HOWEVER the issue i got is they all change to the same value and not there distince product value.

full code.

```
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
<?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>

<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?> 

<script>


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item-options');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].innerHTML = "No Of Devices: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('number_of_devices')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>  || License Period: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('licence_period')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)." !"; ?> ";
}

</script>                       

<?php endforeach ?>
```

To state again i am changing the inner html for the elements with the classname item-options. However the issue i have is they will all change to the last value fot he product. for example lets say we have three products 1,2 and 3. If i use the script all three values should change to 1,2 and 3 however they are all chanigng to 3. I am trying to figure out why this is happning. and how i can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your script updates values in ALL `'item-options'` elements, try to make it without loop (and update only last value):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('item-options'),
    last = elements.lenght - 1;

elements[last].innerHTML = "No Of Devices: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('number_of_devices')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>  || License Period: <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('licence_period')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)." !"; ?> ";
```

p.s. I'm not sure, that your innerHTML is correct. 
And also this method of setting HTML (in `php` code with `JS`) - is not a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you are doing is :
you parse all items in php, and for each item found, you force ERASE ALL the elements item-options one by one to set to the value found in php.
With that, you will change n times ( for n items) the options and you will have only the last one displayed for all your options.

The thing you have to do, is match the item-option in your for with the product you had in php ( for example with the product_id that you added before in your DOM), and if it is the good one, you use your InnerHTML only on this one.
Note that a loop in js isnt necessary anymore if you identify well your item-option by its product_id directly.